# Initiate a dialog from Alexa using a camera

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I am trying to initiate a dialog using an external device.
What I am trying to achieve:

1. Camera detects a person (I am handling the detection. Maybe some
   raspberry pi + webcam + OpenCV)
2. Camera (my device) somehow
   reports that event [that part is the question]
3. Alexa Echo asks
   the preset question
4. User responds to Alexa and Alexa continues
   the dialog as usual

In the current setup, the user has to say "launch {invocation name}", and I want to change that part so when a user comes close to my device, Alexa "starts" the dialog. So I need to trigger the dialog with my device.

I found out that [AWS can be used to interact with Alexa](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/alexa-voice-service/api-overview.html) but I couldn't find anything useful there.
Another thing that I found was [Skill invocation API](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/skill-invocation-api.html). However, it is intended only for testing. Also, it will return the responses to my device instead of an Alexa Echo.

I am not bound to any hardware, I can get rid of Alexa Echo and use my device if I will be able to get the Alexa to use it's mic and speakers.

The general idea is the person comes to my setup, camera detects the person, Alexa asks the person a question and continues from there as like it is a usual skill.

Which libraries or APIs can I use to enable this?

Answer (score 1):

This definitely can be done, but you need to create your own alexa device. By the way, what is your question?

Comment: Thank you for the response. The question is what libraries/interfaces/technologies to look into. Creating my own Alexa device is something that I thought of but didn't find a clear way to send requests.

Comment: The question now is how to initiate a dialog without having to send a voice input for alexa.
I found this and this is a hack that I do not want to use: https://miguelmota.com/blog/alexa-voice-service-with-curl/

Is there a way to send a command to alexa by text?

Comment: The way you "talk to alexa" from an alexa enabled device is HTTP posts. Whatever you do you will need to authorize an Alexa-enabled device. Then you will have to talk to the Alexa mothership via an API (HTTP posts). It could be cCurl or any other program.

Comment: Bespoken (http://bespoken.io) has for instance a software device for testing (https://github.com/bespoken/virtual-device-sdk).

Comment: So you can write a standalone program that uses the camera and if there is movement, you can send the initial "open camera movement skill". But you have to get  a token from Amazon for your HTTP post to be accepted. You cCurl example has the link for the authorization process.

Comment: May I ask what's the purpose of this? I had this idea of Alexa for mute people.

Comment: I am building an interactive bartender, basically. In the current state it requires the client to know how to work with him ("say: alexa, start bartender"). I am trying to improve that by attaching a camera and making it ask the question first ("hi, what do you want to drink?"). I expect that it will make it easier for the clients and more native in general. 
Bespoken is a possible solution but, as I said before, I am trying to avoid hacks in this project. According to bespoken's manuals (https://read.bespoken.io/end-to-end/getting-started/), they do text-to-speech on the server.

Comment: however, if such project exists, I assume, that it is the only possible solution right now. Then I will probably just generate the prompt myself and send it once as I need that only for the launch command triggered by the camera.
If you could confirm that it is the only way to send text commands to Alexa and add this to the answer - I will be happy to accept your answer!

Comment: I cannot confirm 100%, but I'm pretty sure this is the way to talk to Alexa. There is no API to send text commands.